# Get Next Item in Swift Set

Tags: swift, set

I want to get the next item in a `Set<ShopItemCategory>`. I thought I could get the index of the current item as an `Int` and then use that index to get the next item in the same set by adding 1 to it (unless it is the last item in the set, then the index will be set to 0). However, indexOf is not returning an `Int` for me. It is returning type `SetIndex<ShopItemCategory>`. How do I either return a type `Int` index, or cycle the set by 1 item at a time, in some other easier way?

```
mutating func swapCategory() {
    var categoryIndex =
        self.allShopItemCategories.indexOf(self.currentShopItemCategory)
    if categoryIndex == self.allShopItemCategories.count - 1 {
        categoryIndex = 0
    } else {
        categoryIndex++
    }
    self.currentShopItemCategory = self.allShopItemCategories[catIndex!]

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `enumerate()` on the set to get an iterator, but realize `Set`s are inherently unordered.  With an iterator you can work your way through each element, but access order is not guaranteed.  If you want an ordered collection, use an array.

```
var x = Set<Int>()

x.insert(1)
x.insert(2)

for (index, item) in x.enumerate() {
    print("\(item)")
}

// the for loop could print "1,2" or "2,1"...
// there's no way to tell what order the items will be iterated over,
// only that each item *will* be iterated over.
```

Comment: The order of the set is irrelevant. But I don't want to cycle through it all at once. I simply want to set the currentcategory to be the next category in the set every time the user taps a button.

Comment: You should still use an array, because there is no notion of "next category", there is only the notion of "some other element in the set"... You will get varying behavior that will confuse users.  If you use an array then you will have a predictable progression.

Comment: To clarify a bit, think of the `SetIndex` as a private implementation detail related to the `Set` class.  `Array`s are indexable, but `Set`s are not.  `Set` is used to group unique elements so you can ask questions like, "Are the elements in this group present in another group?"  If you start thinking about things in terms of "the next item in the group" you're thinking in terms of *order*, in which case you should be using an array type.

Comment: Cheers, I used an array. I used `find` to get the index of the current category and then add one to it. I guess my version of swift is not the latest because `indexOf` works for arrays in the latest version of swift, and doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. Because elements into a `Set` are not ordered.

On the other hand you can build an Array from your Set and access the elements as you want.

Look at the following example:

```
class Foo<T:Hashable> {
    private let list: [T]
    private var currentIndex = 0
    var nextElm : T {
        currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % list.count
        return list[currentIndex]
    }
    init(set: Set<T>) {
        list = Array(set)
    }
}

let set : Set = [1,2,3]
let foo = Foo(set: set)

foo.nextElm // 3
foo.nextElm // 2
foo.nextElm // 1
foo.nextElm // 3
foo.nextElm // 2
foo.nextElm // 1
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I get an error `Set<T> is not convertable to hashtable` on the declaration of the foo instance.

Comment: Please let me see the code that gives you the error.